# Custom listactivity divider

Tags: android

I have a `ListActivity` that consists of many rows and I'm trying to customize the divider in between rows, so I can give the divider: a corners radius, change its color and apply a border, and so on.

I tried to refer it to a drawable shape layout but it doesn't work; it force closes.

`listactivity` code :

```
public class Rows extends ListActivity {
      String classes[] = { "row1", "row2", "row3",  "row4", "row5"};                    
  @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  ListView lv = getListView();   
  lv.setCacheColorHint(0);  
  lv.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent); 
  lv.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.divider)));  
  lv.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);
  lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_background);

setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, classes));  
}
```

divider.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:height="5dp" android:color="#B22222" /> 
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 
    <padding android:left="10dp"  android:right="10dp"  /> 
    <corners android:radius="10dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
         android:topRightRadius="10dp" /> 
   </shape>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `ColorDrawable` in first place. And if your list params are non-conditional why not setting it all in XML directly:

```
android:divider="@drawable/divider"
```

Comment: my list intiated in code not in xml ,i dont have listview xml ,its listactivity class , so ineed it to created in java code , thanks